# Passing variables from hook_mail to cutom twig template

Tags: theming

Custom twig template into hook_mail()

```
$body_content = array(
    '#theme' => 'mail_body_content',
    '#node' => $node,
);
```

I would like to access to node Entity and display value into the twig

```
myfield_name: {{ node.get('field_myfield_name').value }}
```

Render code

```
$renderedContent = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($body_content);
```

Only myfield_name: is display.
How to get / pass the variable to twig ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using node get to print a value just use this in twig.

> node.field_myfield_name.value

Otherwise preprocess your twig and get only required fields over sending complete node object to twig.

```
function theme_name_preprocess_mail_body_content(&$variables) {
  $variables['myfield_name'] = $variables['node']->field_myfield_name->value; //$variables['node'] will be render $node from your hook_mail() function.
}
```

And in Twig `myfield_name` will work

Answer (score 0):

Passing content (hook_mail):

```php
$body_content = array(
    '#context' => [
        'node' => $node,
    ],
);
$renderedContent = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($body_content);
$message['body'][] = $renderedContent;
```

Get content (twig template file):

```php
myfield_name: {{ context.node.get('field_myfield_name').value }}
```